# Using OpenConnect for a VPN, Linux Mint 17

Tags: networking, linux-mint, vpn, networkmanager

I'm trying to set up a VPN connection. My corporate IT team went and hid under a table when I said Linux so you guys are my last hope. I'm trying to port all my settings from my Windows 7 machine which uses Cisco AnyConnect for a VPN. I have the .xml configuration files (ProgramData/Cisco/Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client), my network certificate (which I extracted into a user and private key cert using OpenSSL) and the CA certificate.

Using the GUI for openconnect, I put in the Gateway, CA, user cert and private key. I get the follow response XML response: **has no "auth" node** and then in the top right of my screen after a few minutes I'll get **the vpn connection 'xxx' failed because there were no valid vpn secrets**. After Googling this issue, most people say to restart network-manager which I have done many times. I also have updated to the latest version of OpenConnect V6.00 which is much newer than the repository version 5.02; both versions had same issue. I have also tried from terminal to make the connection but I get the same issues. I don't know what else to try! On my Windows side there are some .xml profile files (same path as in first paragraph) not sure if I have to  have those linked somehow like the ".../Profile/corparate-profile.xml" file? Any ideas on what to try would be most welcome. I'm not sure of my setup 100% but I have good certs, I pulled the Gateway from "preferences_global.xml (from Windows)" and there is no proxy listed, so they seem right as far as I can tell.